# Add div on html & css next to other div

Tags: html, css

I want to add three divs in the same line, but when I add the second div it's displayed below the first div. I don't know how to fix this problem.

```css
.fisrt-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <img class="img1" src="images/androiddev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b><br><br>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 17px;" href="">blahblahblah</a></b>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 
    17px;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>
```

Comment: use flexbox or grid instead of floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors :

1. Class name `.first-div` not `.fisrt-div` .
2. Property `width`is duplicated.
3. If you want to add `div`'s in the same line, use `Display:inline-block`. [I prefer to do it with flexbox or grid, read more about this]
4. I have noticed that you put `margin-left: 50%;` on `a` style, I think you want to center it, just put `Display:block` and `text-align:center` to the `a` or `span` styles.
5. `float: left;` is not necessary here.
6. You put a very long text inside `b`, that's why I used `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to break text.

```css
.first-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  
}

.second-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <img class="img1" src="images/androiddev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b><br><br>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; text-align:center; font-size: 17px; display: block;" href="">blahblahblah</a></b>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; text-align:center; font-size: 17px; display: block;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your class is written wrong, on the css file.

```css
.fisrt-div
```

Comment: i change it only for the stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

i dont actually get what you're trying to achieve but i hope this helps you.

i removed the float: left

then added display inline-block in css

```css
.fisrt-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.third-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.first-div, .second-div, .third-div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <img class="img1" src="images/androiddev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b><br><br>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 17px;" href="">blahblahblah</a></b>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 
    17px;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>

<div class="third-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 
    17px;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one class for both divs then add the following css

```
div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want the words to wrap use `word-wrap: break-word;`.

If you want both boxes to be the same width, but don' need them to be the same height, make the `height: auto`.

If you want the boxes to have the same height but don't care about width, make the `width: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="first-div">
  <img class="img1" src="images/androiddev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b><br><br>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 17px;" href="">blahblahblah</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 
    17px;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>
```

```css
.main{
    display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.fisrt-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second-div {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
   width: 33.33%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="first-div">
  <img class="img1" src="images/androiddev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b><br><br>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 17px;" href="">blahblahblah</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <img class="img2" src="images/webdev.png">
  <p style="padding: 5px; color: white;"><b>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</b></p>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: turquoise; margin-left: 50%; font-size: 
    17px;">blahblahblah</a>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
</div>
```